# NuGet creates read-only folders for packages without access

Tags: visual-studio, permissions, file-permissions, nuget-package

I am using `Windows 10` with `Visual Studio Community 2017`. I am creating `Xamarin.Forms` project and right after that I am updating `NuGet packages`, but I see `Access denied` error for some `NuGet`package folders. `NuGet` creates these folders in `c:/users/username/.nuget/packages` with `read-only` attribute and after that it has no access to them - `access denied`.

Even I cannot access or manipulate these folders via `File explorer`, but I am with administrator account and there is no another Windows account.

I am using `Visual Studio` as `Administrator`, but I can't update/restore packages or clear `NuGet cache`.

Comment: Do you get something like that? Executing nuget actions took 2,64 min
This collection is read-only. in Output Window. Me, too.

Comment: Have you close all VS instances and restart the PC to check if you can access that folder?

Comment: After restarting `Windows` I have access to these folder, but after that if update/restore packages for the project, there is access denied error, again. Erik, I don't get your error, only  access denied.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have suppress the folder Cache at C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Xamarin.Android for resolve this problem